# The AdjustText library isn't adjusting matplotlib text label positions

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use the adjusttext library to adjust the positioning of text labels for a matplotlib scatter plot, so that they don't overlap with eachother and are generally more readable.

I've tried various different parameter options (see 4 attempts below, I have tried each of these seperately in turn) for this library but none of which seem to be having any effect at all. The diagram remains entirely the same regardless.

This is the code I tried.

Also, if relevant, when I run the following line of code in the cell after the diagram:

*print(texts)
*
I get this result below. Which made be think that somehow the adjusttext library is only referencing one of the 100+ "players" whose names are being plotted on this diagram.

[Text(4.164408947686031, 8.229260658112585, 'Xander Schauffele')]

```
from adjustText import adjust_text
# define criteria for filtering the data
min_scaled_rank = 0
max_scaled_rank = 5
min_back_win = 1.0
max_back_win = 200

# filter the data based on the criteria
filtered_data = df_nonzero[(df_nonzero['Scaled Rating'] >= min_scaled_rank) & (df_nonzero['Scaled Rating'] <= max_scaled_rank) & (df_nonzero['Back Win'] >= min_back_win) & (df_nonzero['Back Win'] <= max_back_win)]
# create a scatter plot for each player in the filtered data
groups = filtered_data.groupby('Player')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
for name, group in groups:
    ax.scatter(group['Scaled Rating'], group['Back Win'])
    texts = [ax.text(group['Scaled Rating'].iloc[i], group['Back Win'].iloc[i], txt) for i, txt in enumerate(group['Player'])]

# adjust the positions of the text labels
#adjust_text(texts, autoalign=False)
#adjust_text(texts, autoalign=True, force_points=0.2, force_text=0.2, expand_points=(1.2, 1.2), expand_text=(1, 1), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle = '-', lw=0.1, alpha = 0))
#adjust_text(texts, autoalign=False, force_points=0.5, force_text=0.5, expand_points=(1.5, 1.5), expand_text=(1.2, 1.2), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle = '-', lw=0.1, alpha = 0.5))
adjust_text(texts, force_text=0.5, expand=(1.5, 1.5))

# add x and y axis labels and a title
ax.set_xlabel('Scaled Rating')
ax.set_ylabel('Back Win')
ax.set_title('Back Win vs Weighted Rank')

# display the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Well, yes, because you overwrite the `texts` variable in each loop.  When the loop ends, only the last one will be there.  You need `texts=[]` before the loop, and `texts.append` in the loop.